# Agregar subtitulos de forma remota en Un video en ANGULAR Reproductor de video (plyr)

Tags: angular, video

Quiero agregar mis subtitulos que estoy extrayendo desde mi base de datos en angular 14, pero no me funciona con un ngFor en el  por lo que recurri a hacerlo en el ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
let tiempoVisualizacion:number;

this.player = new Plyr('#player', {
  i18n: {
    captions: 'Subtítulos',
    quality: 'Calidad',
    speed: 'Velocidad',
    disabled: 'Deshabilitado'
  },
  quality: {
    default: 720, // Calidad predeterminada
    options: [576, 720, 1080], // Opciones de calidad disponibles
    forced: true, // Habilitar calidad automática
    onChange: (quality: number) => {
      console.log('Calidad seleccionada:', quality);
      
    }
  }
  
      
    });
 this.loadSubtitles();
}
```

No se que otra manera hay para poder cargarlos, si es que tengo que eliminar esto puedo eliminarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Esto tengo en

```
loadSubtitles(): void {
    if (this.player) {
      const tracks: Plyr.Track[] = [];
  
      for (const subtitulo of this.subtitulos) {
        const track: Plyr.Track = {
          kind: 'captions',
          label: subtitulo.Idioma,
          srcLang: 'es',
          src: subtitulo.Url,
          default: false
        };
        console.log(track);
        
        tracks.push(track);
      }
  
       /
    const newSource: Plyr.SourceInfo = {
      type: this.player.source.type,
      title: this.player.source.title,
      sources: this.player.source.sources,
      poster: this.player.source.poster,
      tracks: tracks, // Agregar las pistas de subtítulos aquí
      previewThumbnails: this.player.source.previewThumbnails
    };
    console.log(newSource);
    
    /
    this.player.source = newSource;

    this.player.restart();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hola DanielDaniel, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos. ver como responder aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.